# Seeking FOSS .NET image processing "lasso" selector

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

Before I reinvent the wheel ...

I'm coding in C#, so need a .NET solution. I want to process a gray-scale image which can be broken down into areas, which can be defined as having a lower & upper colour threshold (or "darkness") - none of which overlap and to identify various sections of the image - lasso style, as in a paint program.

When identified I want the software to either deliniate the areas with a border of a given colo(u)r or to return a list of x/y co-ords which represent the border.

Is there a FOSS solution which can be used in a commercial project? (the more liberal the license the better, in case I have to tweak the source) Failing that, can anyone point me at an algorithm?

Thansk in advance

Comment: It is a big package, but Paint.NET was modified MIT license before version 3.36.  Any fork < 3.36 would have this functionality with MIT license compatibility.  It sounds like you are just wanting the lasso, but that is going to be a hard find in a single library.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I'll look into that. Yes, it's a big package, but may have to live with it. Otehrwise, roll my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AForge.net is really good, i've used it in a few projects.

http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

I remember it has the following at least:

- Edge detectors: sobel, difference, canny, homogeneity
- Corners' detectors: SUSAN, Moravec

However it is GNU Lesser GPL

Comment: +1 Thanks. LPGL? not optimal, but as long as I can use it as a library and don't have to change any of it's code then it's ok use commercially.  I'll try it & see - it will either work or it won't

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need an edge detection algorithm. If so, a quick web search shows that there are various libraries and source available, for example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Laplace_Gaussion_edge.aspx.

A similar question was also asked on here: [Edge detection on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899987/edge-detection-on-c) (similar but not quite the same, so I don't think your question is a duplicate).

Comment: I googled, of course. There are soem interesting pojects on google source, but that link to a previous question alwo opened up new avenues of exploration. Thanks (+1)

Comment: Great. I think just realizing that this is a form of edge detection is a good start, so I'm glad that was helpful. Even if you want to write it yourself the algorithms are not too hard and it's quite interesting (although I may be biased as image proc was my Masters thesis topic...).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the license which is free for FOSS projects, but not for commerical (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Licensing:). I think you'll find everything you need. I haven't used, but I've seen other recommend http://code.google.com/p/aforge/